# Hooking textfield upto search button next to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

On this web page;

- I have a textfield which is next to a search button.
- The search button calls some javascript to do the searching.
- At the moment, after you type in the search terms in the search textfield, and hit the enter button - nothing happens and it is not connected to the search button.

How would I make it so that the search button is "hooked up to the" text field ?

Is the only way to use the `onkeydown` of the input box, then check in that function which key was pressed? seems a bit dirty

Comment: Any reason not to put the field and button in a form?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned the searchfilter uses AJAX, so in form it seems to be causing a post, page refreshes and search terms lost

Answer (score 1):

Put them into a form, change the button type to 'submit', then call your javascript function on the form's 'onsubmit'.

Like so:

```
<form onsubmit="jsFunction();">
     <input type="text" />
     <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, put them in a form and:

```
$('#yourform').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    // do stuff.
  })
});
```

On other matters, you could always make the form `method="GET"` to avoid your `POST` issue.